# Is it possible to force-write to an unrecognized SD card?

Tags: formatting, serial-port, storage, usbserial

I have an SD card that I am trying to salvage, but whenever I plug it in to my Macbook, it doesn't show up. I know the issue is not with the card reader because it can pick up several other cards just fine. Would it be possible to plug it in and then force a format operation pointed to the port where it supposedly is?

UPDATE: Question moved to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1724055/1697323).

Comment: SuperUser is the site you want, not Stack Overflow. This is a general computing question, not a programming question.

Comment: Done. That definitely seems like a better place @DavidMakogon . I am not too familiar with the other Stack Exchange sites, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction!